# physical significance of attribute learning

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection, transfer-learning

Just reading an article on attribute learning and its usage in transfer learning and novelty detection. I have one doubt pertaining to this phenomenon.

What is the outcome of attribute learning ? Are we getting optimized values for the attributes describing an instance of training data or the attributes meaningful enough to describe the training data ?

If we are getting attributes, then how are the values for these attributes chosen to describe the training instances.

An easier way to put my question could be - "Assuming attribute learning to be a black box, what are the inputs given to this black box and what is the outcome emanating out of it ?"

Also, is there a difference between "attribute description" and "attribute value" ?